# Is $A = \{0, 1, x, y\}$ a field with addition and multiplication defined by a table?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $A = \{0, 1, x, y\}$ be a set with four elements. Explain why the set $A$, with addition and multiplication defined by the two tables below, is not a field.

[image]

Comment: i am pretty sure that x has no Multiplicative inverse if 1 is the neutral number for (*)

Comment: Hey, please show what you've tried (the actual work you've done), in your post, directly.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2467789/9464

Answer (score 1):

Because $y\ne 1$ and $xy=x$. This cannot happen in any domain.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have $x \ne 0$ and therefore should have a multiplicative inverse. But then you have $x^2=0$ which implies $x^{-1}x^2=x^{-1}0$, i.e., $x=0$. Contradiction.